# SSL certificate path with Ruby EventMachine HttpRequest

Tags: ruby

How to provide SSL certificate file/path in options when making HttpRequest call using EventMachine in Ruby when SSL verify_peer is true?
(I want to validate the server certificate at the client side)

I have the code this way...

```
options = {:head => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
   :ssl =>{:verify_peer => true}
  }
```

`http_request = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("URL", options).get`

I heard that some ca_file , ca_path is used. 
 Also, please suggest the EventMachine gem version that the solution works.

If I am not right, do I need to handle this certificate validation in callback methods?

Answer (score 0):

I found the working solution for my above question.

I made a monkey patch with EM Http SLL patch provided by Faraday lib and it got solved.

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/a712938071bb0997410b5de4a4f2517d30fc4d3d/lib/faraday/adapter/em_http_ssl_patch.rb

```
options = {:head => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
   :ssl =>{:verify_peer => true, :cert_chain_file => "path/to/PEM/file"}
  }
```

And yes, the certificate validation is handled in the callback methods of the monkey patch.